# How can I join a table to get values similar to the Excel VLOOKUP-Range-Function?

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm using **HP Vertica** to write my queries. I want to select some data which should look like Excel would do it when you use the `VLOOKUP` function with the **range flag enabled** [ VLOOKUP(A1;B1:C4;2;**1**) ].

I give you one simple example for better understanding. I have a table showing historic warehouse movements.

```
stock_history 
-------------

|product|location|time_stamp  |
|-------|--------|------------|
| A     | Loc A  | 2015-01-13 |
| A     | Loc B  | 2015-03-13 |
```

- **Product A** was moved in **location A** in **January**
- (and stayed there in **February**)
- and was moved in **location B** in **March**

Now I want to see the Location of A at **every** month (let's say there is only one movement allowed per month to make it easier)

It should look like this

```
|product|location|month    |
|-------|--------|----- ---|
| A     | Loc A  | 2015-01 |
| A     | Loc A  | 2015-02 |
| A     | Loc B  | 2015-03 |
```

I've generated a table which shows all months:

```
all_months
----------

|month    |
|---------| 
| 2015-01 |
| 2015-02 |
| 2015-03 |
```

Here is a statement I tried

```
select his.product
     , his.location
     , mon.month

from stock_history as his

left outer join all_months as mon
on mon.month = to_char( time_stamp, 'YYYY-MM' )

|product |location|month    |
|--------|--------|----- ---|
| A      | Loc A  | 2015-01 |
| (null) | (null) | 2015-02 |
| A      | Loc B  | 2015-03 |
```

How do I manage it to get the product A also in the February-line, because it still was in location A in February?

Thanks for reading my question. I'm looking forward to get your answers ;)

Regards,
Felix

Comment: Are you doing this for one product or all products?

Comment: I'm doing this for all products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go !
I have also added example with added months.Made use of recursive features.
I tested with oracle, should work with vertica also.

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(PRODUCT CHAR(1),LOCATION VARCHAR(10),MONTHS VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO A (PRODUCT,LOCATION,MONTHS)
SELECT 'A','LOC A','2015-01' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'A','LOC B','2015-03' FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE MONTHS
(MON VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO MONTHS(MON)
SELECT '2015-01' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '2015-02' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '2015-03' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '2015-04' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '2015-05' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '2015-06' FROM DUAL
COMMIT

WITH CTE (I,PRODUCT,LOCATION,MON) AS
(
SELECT 1 I,BASE.PRODUCT,A.LOCATION,M.MON
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT FROM A)BASE
CROSS JOIN 
MONTHS M
LEFT JOIN A
ON A.MONTHS=M.MON
UNION ALL
SELECT I+1,PRODUCT,COALESCE(LOCATION,LAG(LOCATION)OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY MON)) AS LOC,MON
FROM 
CTE WHERE I<12
)
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT,LOCATION,MON FROM CTE WHERE LOCATION IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY MON
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the month/product combinations using a `cross join`.  Then use a correlated subquery to get the location from the most recent or current month:

```
select mon.month, p.product,
       (select sh.location
        from stock_history sh
        where mon.month <= to_char(sh.time_stamp, 'YYYY-MM' ) and p.product = sh.product
        order by mon.month desc
        limit 1
       ) as location
from (select distinct product p from stock_history) p cross join
     all_months mon;
```